# Access 2007: Refresh Parent Form from datasheet view in subform

Tags: ms-access

I have a parent form named frmProject.  There is a Total Time text box called txtTotalTime - the data control source does a DLookUp for a query that adds together time spent.

The subform on the Project Form is called frmProjectHistory.  The default view of it is datasheet view.

I've tried setting the On Dirty event for frmProjectHistory to Me![frmProject].requery or Me![frmProject].[txtTotalTime].requery (or Forms! inplace of Me!).  each time I get "can't find the object" followed by the Me!frmProject....

I'm needing to update the Total Time box on frmProject every time either a new record is entered in the subform datasheet view - or when time is adjusted for a previous event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since frmProjectHistory is the child form you can't reference the parent with the `Me` keyword.  Write out the whole reference -  `Forms.frmProject.txtTotalTime.Requery` in VBA or `=[Forms]![frmProject]![txtTotalTime].Requery` from the properties window.

Also, I think you should use `AfterUpdate` event.  I believe the `OnDirty` fires before the changes are actually saved.

Comment: Thank you, now it's telling me Access can't find the object 'Forms.'  if I change it to "Forms![frmProject].[txtTotalTime].Requery" it gives the same error. "Access can't find the object 'Forms!frmProject.'

Comment: double-check the spelling of the form name

Comment: The parent form is "frmProject" (copied from properties view). name of the text box to be updated is "txtTotalTime"
  `Forms![frmProject].[txtTotalTime].Requery`

Comment: Are you using an event procedure or are you typing that right into the properties window?

Comment: i was typing it into the properties window.

Comment: Ok, try `=[Forms]![frmProject]![txtTotalTime].Requery`

Comment: `Forms![frmProject].[Form].[txtTotalTime].Requery` you need to add the `Form` object before refering to a txtBox

Comment: Mike, thank you for your perseverance, it didn't work though, kept giving me the can't find the object error.

parakmiakos - that worked!

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need to requery all the data on the Parent form? If so, you just use:

```
Me.Parent.Requery
```

If you want to only refresh that one text box, then try different variations of:

```
Me.Parent.txtTotalTime.Requery
```

or

```
Me.Parent.Form.txtTotalTime.Requery
```